# Mishnah Berurah 47:30 on saying morning brachos at night

Tags: mishnah-berurah

The Mishnah Berurah 47:30 writes:

> Even if one rises after midnight for some purpose and intends to go back and sleep a further settled sleep subsequently, he may nevertheless say all these morning blessings then and will no longer have to say them when he gets up in the morning. This applies to all the morning blessings apart from the blessing Elokay Neshamah, which he should say then without the conclusion, and the blessing Ha-Ma’avir Sheynah, which he should say then without mention of the Divine Name. When he gets up subsequently in the morning, he should say these two blessings with mention of the Divine Name and the fact that He is King, as they should properly be said.

Does the fact that he writes “even if one rises after midnight” imply that if one rose before midnight, or if he did not sleep at all, he should not say the morning blessings until it is actually dawn? And what does he mean by “for some purpose”? If he awakens for no purpose at all would the din be different?

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into "for some purpose." לאיזה ענין could be translated as "for whatever reason." The point is that he's not getting up for the day but just waking up temporarily.